# Show each div step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to make this script to show my div step by step. The current code will only show all the div on click. How do i make it detect the div and show step by step.Ex:1st click => expand div for step 1 , 2nd clikc => expand div for step2. After that if the div is all expanded , when the button is clicked then hide all the div.

TQ

```
<div id="stepshow">
  <h3>Step 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="stepshow">
  <h3>Step 2</h3>
</div>

<button id="stepbtn"></button>

<script>
  var qqcounter = 1;
  var maxstep = 3;
  $("#stepbtn").text("Show step " + qqcounter);
  $("#stepshow").hide();

  $("#stepbtn").click(function(){
    qqcounter++;
    if(qqcounter < maxstep)
    {
      $("#stepbtn").text("Show step " + qqcounter);
      $("#stepshow").slideDown();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#stepbtn").text("Hide step");
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to show/hide:

http://jsfiddle.net/rVwkn/14/

**jQuery:**

```
$('#stepbtn').click( function() {  
  if ($('#step2').is(':visible')) {
      $('#step3').show();
      $('#stepbtn').hide();
  } else if ($('#step1').is(':visible')) {
      $('#step2').show();
  }
});

$('#backbtn').click( function() {  
  if ($('#step3').is(':visible')) {
      $('#step3').hide();
      $('#stepbtn').show();
  } else if ($('#step1').is(':visible')) {
      $('#step1').hide();
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
    #step2 {
        display:none;
    }
    #step3 {
        display:none;
    }
    #backbtn { display: none }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="step1">
      <h3>Step 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="step2">
      <h3>Step 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="step3">
      <h3>Step 3</h3>
    </div>

    <button id="stepbtn">Next Step</button>
    <button id="backbtn">Go Back a Step</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is another version as well, which gives you more flexibility:

http://jsfiddle.net/ddr6D/6/

**jQuery:**

```
            $(document).ready( function() {
                var current_step = 1;
                var max_number_of_steps = 6;
               $('#stepbtn').click( function() {  
                  var next_step = current_step + 1;
                  $('#step'+next_step).slideDown();
                  $('#backbtn').show();
                  current_step++; // increase the step we are on...
                  if (current_step == max_number_of_steps) {
                    $('#stepbtn').hide();
                  }
               });

               $('#backbtn').click( function() {  
                  $('#step'+current_step).slideUp();// hide it first,
                  current_step--; // now update, so we know the correct step we are on
                  if (current_step == 1) {
                    $('#backbtn').hide();
                  }
                   if (current_step < max_number_of_steps) {
                       $('#stepbtn').show(); // show, if its been hidden...
                   }
               }); 

            });
```

**CSS:**

```
            #step2,#step3,#step4,#step5,#step6 {
                display:none;
            }
            #backbtn { display: none }
```

**HTML:**

```
            <div id="step1">
              <h3>Step 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="step2">
              <h3>Step 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="step3">
              <h3>Step 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="step4">
              <h3>Step 4</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="step5">
              <h3>Step 5</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="step6">
              <h3>Step 6</h3>
            </div>

            <button id="stepbtn">Next Step</button>
            <button id="backbtn">Go Back a Step</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the example but i am looking forward for a better solution incase i have many step :)

Comment: No worries - try the new one above :)

Comment: Thank You , but im looking only to manipulate one button. is that possible ? Tq

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The extra "back" and "next" buttons were a boo-boo (must have copied over a bit too much from jsfiddle :)). If you want a back **AND** forward button, there isn't a way to have just one button.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div id="stepshow1" class="stepshow">
            <h3>Step 1</h3>
        </div>
  <div id="stepshow2" class="stepshow">
            <h3>Step 2</h3>
        </div>
  <div id="stepshow3" class="stepshow">
            <h3>Step 3</h3>
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="stepbtn" />
```

script

```
var qqcounter = 0;
var maxstep = 4;
$("#stepbtn").text("Show step " + qqcounter);
$(".stepshow").hide();
$("#stepbtn").attr('value', 'Show step' + (qqcounter+1));
$("#stepbtn").click(function () {
    console.log(qqcounter);
    qqcounter++;
    if (qqcounter < maxstep) {
        $("#stepbtn").attr('value', 'Show step' + (qqcounter + 1));
        $('#stepshow' + qqcounter).slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("#stepbtn").attr('value', 'Hide step');
        $(".stepshow").hide();
        qqcounter = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, cause you have the same ids "stepshow" you should change it for smth like "stepshow_1" for example:

```
$('btn').click(function(){

    $('#stepshow_'+counter).show();
    counter++;

});
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uD3W2/2/

Comment: so how do i hide my step in the first ?

Comment: You can use partial selector like $('div[id^="stepshow_"]')

Comment: how about the hide step ? how do i define after hide step on click will hide all ?

Comment: So you need to hide steps the one after another, like you've been showing them ?

Comment: @Good.luck - my version already does that (a "back" button for steps 2+)

Comment: @AndrewNewby my does it too, take a look on fiddle, if you want steps 2+ just change the maxstep var and add more steps.

Comment: @Good.luck - ah ok , didn't realise you had updated your fiddle =) TMTOWTDI